# Imputing missing values for a RM-ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, missing-data, data-imputation

I have 4 experimental groups/conditions and 5 measurement times for each group/condition. Each participant only took part in one of the 1 conditions. In total there are 27 participants and each condition has around 6 participants.

In my data set, several participants are missing a value during one of the 5 measurement times. So there are several cases (rows) where the participant does not have 5 measurement times but only 4 for example. The missing values are completely random and exist in all conditions.

My problem is the following. Because RM-ANOVA does case-wise deletion I end up with around 6 fewer cases which severely impacts my results.

What I am wondering is if it is feasible to impute the missing data using a regression for example. And how many values can I impute before it is no longer feasible?

Comment: Maybe repeated measurements via mixed models, where this is no problem?

Answer (score 0):

A mixed model for repeated measures would implicitly impute these values assuming that they were missing at random. That can make sense, or may be inappropriate depending on which question you wish to answer. E.g. if in a study of a drug people stop taking the drug and stop participating in the study, fitting such a model to the on-drug data of all patients makes sense if you want to know what would have happened if they had stayed on drug and in the study (but not if you want to know what happened after they stopped taking the drug, when drug effects presumably would go away). Such a model or a multivariate normal model lets you also impute the missing values (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbmi/vignettes/stat_specs.html) for a more in-depth discussion in the context of a particular R package or for a fully Bayesian version [this merge request](https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/pull/1435) from the latest release of the brms R package, which added support for an unstructured correlation matrix between timepoints).